# Form select does not pass information to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have created a form using a dropdown list. A value must be selected before the form is submitted, but the PHP file does not receive the selected value. My code is as follows:

HTML

```
<form id="rightform" method="POST" action="../../php/Update.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Sale Status: </label>
        <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select Status</option>
            <option value="" disabled>-----</option>
            <option value="Delivered">Delivered</option>
            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="No Deal">No Deal</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Comments: </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment" name="comment" required>
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="verify()" class="btn btn-default" id="update">
        Send Feedback
    </button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
        Reset Fields
    </button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function verify(){
    if(!document.getElementById('comment').value.trim().length){
        alert("Please enter a comment for the status you are submitting");
        document.getElementById('rightform').onsubmit = function() {return false;};
    } else {
        document.getElementById('rightform').onsubmit = function() {return true;};
    }
 }
```

PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'connectdb.php';

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        $sub_status = $_POST['status'];
        if($sub_status == NULL) {
            echo "Status is null";
        } else {            
            echo $sub_status;
        }
    }
?>
```

This always displays that the status is null. I have tried this over and over, and have not found anything wrong with the code. Perhaps I am missing something important? 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might be missing something too, but I see nothing that would cause this. I'd probably `print_r($_POST);` next to see what's submitted. It might also be helpful to use your browsers' dev tools to see what's sent to the server.

Comment: I just pasted this code into my localhost and it works perfectly.

Comment: The code works. Maybe it's a caching issue? Have you tried it with a different browser?

Comment: That JS appears to only ensure that `comment` is not empty, not `status`.

Comment: I seem to have resolved it now. It was not a caching issue. Instead, I used $_POST['status'] directly instead of assigning it to a variable first. Not exactly certain why this happened, but it worked.